# odataV4 filter contains with case sensitive and incase sensitive

Tags: c#, .net, odata

i have tried to filter contains with case sensitive in oData.  but it not working. please find the query string

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees/?$filter=contains(toupper(FirstName),%27C%27)

http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees/?$filter=contains(tolower(FirstName),%27C%27)
```

it return both lower and upper case . it is possible to achieve?

Comment: [documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html) says this is possible, but I can't get a case sensitive server side filter to work.

Comment: Would you please file an issue at: https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/issues

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying database engine uses a case *insensitive* collation, then by default all queries against that engine will ignore case when executing comparisons, even if we try to use functions to manipulate the case of field or parameter values.

So even if the OData parser is correctly translating your request into the a statement similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE LOWER(FirstName) LIKE '%C%'
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE UPPER(FirstName) LIKE '%C%'
```

In a *CI* collation, both statements will return records that have both 'C' or 'c'.
There is no OOTB support for casting to a *case sensitive* collation for the comparison field from an OData query

> The OData query engine in .Net generally operates as a translator between convention based URL queries into Linq-to-Entity expresssions, if you are using EF as an ORM to SQL server, then these entity queries resolve to SQL statements.

---

I have seen some other similar posts that suggest you can set `EnableCaseInsensitive=false` on the `ODataUriResolver` however this will only affect resolution of Controller, Entity and Property names, it will not affect the evaluation of string value comparisons.